# difference in array is minimum

Tags: java, arrays

the question is :
You have a number of stones with known weights w1, …, wn. Write a program that will rearrange the stones into two piles such that weight difference between the piles is minimal.

INPUT:
Input contains the number of stones n (1 ≤ n ≤ 20) and weights of the stones w1, …, wn (integers, 1 ≤ wi ≤ 100000) delimited by white spaces.

OUTPUT:
output a number representing the minimal possible weight difference between stone piles.

im worked on this question and have written code which is working fine. but im failing for few test cases( i dont have the test cases as it is an online compiler)  im not able to figure it out if i have missed something with respect to the above question. kindly help if someone finds a mistake in my code. thanks in advance. my code below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int b1 = 1;
        int q = 0;
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter no. of stones");
        b1 = in.nextInt();
        if (b1 >= 1 && b1 <= 20) {
            int[] z = new int[b1];

            System.out.println("enter the weights of the stones seperated by a space: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < b1; i++) {
                z[i] = in.nextInt();
            }

            if (z.length >= 1 && z.length <= 10000) {
                for (int i = 0; i < z.length - 1; i++) {
                    q = Math.abs(z[i + 1] - z[i]);
                    l.add(q);
                }
                Collections.sort(l);
                System.out.println(l.get(0));
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

input: N= 5, weights: 2 6 48 96 25( my own test case)
output: 4

Comment: Please format the code properly and use proper variable names to emphasize what you are doing.

Comment: Seconding @barq here -- names like `z`, `l`, and `q` are totally uninformative and make your program much harder to debug. `numberList` might work better instead of `l`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and  sorry for the inconvenience. will follow the naming standards going forward.

Comment: Unless you can provide test cases that are failing nobody is likely to be able to help you.